# Totalling the matching values of a dataframe column with Series values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Series :

```
350    0
254    1
490    0
688    0
393    1
30     1
```

and a dataframe :

```
       0   outcome
0    350     1
1    254     1
2    490     0
3    688     0
4    393     0
5     30     1
```

The below code to count the total number of matches between the Series and the outcome column in the dataframe is what was intended. 
Is there any other better way besides the below?

```
i=0
match=0
for pred in results['outcome']:
    if test.values[i] == pred:
        match+=1
    i+=1
print match
```

I tried using `results['Survived'].eq(labels_test).sum()` but the answer is wrong.
And using lambda but the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can compare by mapping series i.e

```
(df['0'].map(s) == df['outcome']).sum()

4
```

Comment: Short and clever! (I'm not sure if this will work in all cases though, let's wait for OP).

Answer (score 2):

First, align the dataframe and series using [`align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html).

```
df, s = df.set_index('0').align(s, axis=0)
```

Next, compare the `outcome` column with the values in `s` and count the number of `True` values -

```
df.outcome.eq(s).sum()
4
```

Comment: I have to admit `align` is new to me

Comment: @Dark Learned from the best (piR).

Comment: nice, i've never seen `.align()` method before... Shame on me it's there since version 0.17.0

Comment: @MaxU It's a very handy method! It aligns the two objects such that their index is identical. Missing entries become NaN. If you pass a dataframe instead of a series, the columns will also get aligned (if you don't pass an axis param that is).